# Descent directions at stationary points using definition of the notation little-o - o()

Tags: limits, derivatives, optimization, gradient-descent, stationary-point

Assume that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^2$ with $\nabla f(x) = 0$ and $\nabla^2f(x)$ indefinite (with both positive and negative eigenvalue(s)) for some point $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $f$ admits descent directions (in the weak sense) at $x$.

**answer**:
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, C^2$ with $\nabla f(\textbf{x}) = 0$ (x is a stationary point) and $\nabla^2f(\textbf{x})$ is indefinite (x is a saddle point)

A descent direction in the weak sense is defined as:
$$
d\in \mathbb{R}^n, \exists \varepsilon >0, \forall \lambda \in (0,\varepsilon) \quad f(\textbf{x} + \lambda d) <f(\textbf{x})
$$
A second order Taylor expansion gives, for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\textbf{d}\in \mathbb{R}^n$
\begin{align*}
f(\textbf{x} + \lambda \textbf{d}) &= f(\textbf{x}) + \underbrace{\lambda \nabla f(\textbf{x})^\top \textbf{d}}_{=0} + \lambda^2\textbf{d}^\top\nabla^2 f(\textbf{x})\textbf{d} + o(\|\lambda \textbf{d}\|^2)\\
&= f(\textbf{x}) + \lambda^2 \textbf{d}^\top\nabla^2f(\textbf{x})d+o(\lambda^2\|\textbf{d}\|^2)
\end{align*}
Let $\textbf{d}$ be a normed eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\alpha < 0$ of $\nabla^2f(\textbf{x})$. Then: 
$$
f(\textbf{x}+\lambda \textbf{d}) = f(\textbf{x}) + \lambda^2\alpha \underbrace{\|\textbf{d}\|^2}_{=1}+ o(\lambda^2)
$$
As $o(\lambda^2)$ is negligible compared to $\lambda^2\alpha$ when $\lambda \rightarrow 0$, we know that 
$$
\exists \eta >0, \forall \lambda \leq \eta \qquad \|o(\lambda^2)\|< \|\alpha \lambda^2\|
$$
So for $\lambda \leq \eta$
$$\underbrace{\lambda^2\alpha}_{<0} + \underbrace{o(\lambda^2)}_{?} <0
$$
Therefore 
$$f(\textbf{x} + \lambda \textbf{d}) = f(\textbf{x}) + \lambda^2\alpha + o(\lambda^2)<f(\textbf{x}) \quad \text{for } \lambda \in (0,\eta)
$$
$f$ admits a descent direction in $\textbf{x}$

**Here is my question**:
I have trouble understanding the following sentence: As $o(\lambda^2)$ is negligible compared to $\lambda^2\alpha$ when $\lambda \rightarrow 0$. It has probably to do with my lack of understanding of little o

Here is the definition I found:

Intuitively, the assertion "$f(x)$ is $o(g(x))$" (read "$f(x)$ is little-o of $(g(x))$") means that $g(x)$ **grows much faster than** $f(x)$.

Or

As $g(x)$ is nonzero, or at least becomes nonzero beyond a certain point, the relation $f(x) = o(g(x))$ is equivalent to
$$
\lim_{x \to \inf}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0 
$$

Those two definitions define the relationship of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ when $x$ tends to infinity. In our case $x$ (or $\lambda$) tends to zero. How can we make a paralell?